# Smart Contract as Part of Consensus Layer | Consensus enforced by Smart Contract

Tags: consensus

Often, consensus (POS/POW,PBFT,IBFT) is not associated with smart contract. but smart contract can also be further used enforce consensus as well?

Perhaps to further breakdown consensus, there is business consensus (Smart Contract Enforced) and technical consensus (E.g. no two similar transaction in a similar block)?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Apologies - the question is if Smart Contract also serve also a sort of consensus as business logic can be placed in it?